# Hide Regedit field

Tags: winlogon

I'm working on an app that has to auto login in windows, the idea is to modify the register using this command:
`REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d <password> /f` .

The problem is that I need the password to not be visible if somebody checks the register, is there any way to hide this field? or to encrypt it?